# Finding and fixing giant white space at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

On this page https://fathercraft.soulheart.co/baby-essential-list/, I'm getting a huge white space at the bottom of the page. I can't find any obvious reason why, and I'm not getting it on my local development install or on any other page of the site.

I've used the devtools inspector to look through the DOM and can't find anything suspicious.

I've tried the basic `* { border: 1px solid red; }` technique, and nothing seems to be present below the body of my site. There's just an enormous white space down there. Maybe it could be JavaScript-related, but I'm not sure where that would be coming from.

I've reviewed all of the suggested "questions that may already have your answer" and they did not help. I appreciate any help you can give. I'm at a total loss here.

Comment: .site-container{ overflow: hidden}

Comment: Just add this to your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an image in .page-baby-essentials .accordion-content-section::before which is 
./assets/images/rawpixel-604758-unsplash.png

Comment: Ah, that was it, thanks! I thought I had removed that from my  CSS. Must have reverted to an earlier commit that still had that there.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to quickly track down issues like this is to delete sections of HTML until your issue is disappears using your browser's developer tools window (often <kbd>F12</kbd>).

You can use `CTRL/CMD+Z` to undo a deletion then traverse down the tree, deleting its children to pin point it.

Also, if you can't find an issue by hovering over an element then the odds are that it's a before/after element, so you can start there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tips! That will save me some time next time.